# internal server error while navigating php pages

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, wamp

I am fetching data from mysql table and populating table in HTML .In each table row i have remove button that calls remove.php and remove that row from mysql table and again return to admin.php.
Problem is when i click the remove button it is executing the php script removing row from table in the database.Then i am navigating again to admin.php
While navigating wamp server gives 500 Internal Server error.
What i want is to execute delete query and again return to admin.php. So that admin.php gives me updated data. I am understanding what is going wrong.

This is my logged error:
 [Mon Feb 25 15:19:30.182141 2019] [http:error] [pid 1852:tid 1232] [client ::1:57588] AH02429: Response header name 'location ' contains invalid characters, aborting request, referer: http://localhost/project_exhibition/admin.php

This is my admin.php

```html
<?php

//  if(isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && ($_SESSION["loggedin"] == true) && $_SESSION["usertype"] == a){
// }
// else{
//  header("location: login.php");
//  exit;
// }
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('here');</script>";

require_once "config.php";
$sql = "SELECT userid,username FROM user_login_table";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
if($stmt->execute())
{
 echo "executed";
}
else{
 echo "not able to execute";
}
$stmt->store_result();
echo $stmt->num_rows;
$stmt->bind_result($id,$name);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>HTML Table</h2>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Username</th>
    <th>Remove</th>
  </tr>

  <?php
  $rowid=0; 
 while ($stmt->fetch()) {
  $rowid += 1;
        echo "<tr>
        <td>".
        $id."
        </td>
        <td>".
        $name."
        </td> 
        <td>
        <form action='remove.php' method='post'>
        <input type='hidden' name ='row_id' value = ".$id." >
        <input type='submit' value='Remove'>
        </form>
        </td> 
        </tr>";
    }  ?>
 
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

this is remove.php

```html
<?php

require_once "config.php" ;
echo "string";
$sql = "DELETE FROM user_login_table where userid=".$_POST['row_id']."";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
if($stmt->execute())
{
 header("location : admin.php");
}
else
{ 
 echo "alert('Failed to Remove.Something went wrong')";
 echo "failed";
}
//header("location : admin.php");

?>
```

config.php

```html
<?php
define('DB_SERVER','localhost');
define('DB_USER','root');
define('DB_PASSWORD','');
define('DB_NAME','exhibition_database');

$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);

if($mysqli === false )
{
 die("Error! Couldn't connect. ". $mysqli->connect_error );
}
?>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Do try and get out of the habit of cluttering up your code with needless things like `=== false`. Many functions are designed to return values that evaluate as logically true or false so that's redundant and in some cases can cause bugs.

Comment: Tip: "500 Internal Server error" means you need to check your server logs to see what happened more specifically. PHP will often log in great detail the exact problem down to the line of code where the problem occurred.

Comment: @tadman this is the log [Mon Feb 25 15:19:30.182141 2019] [http:error] [pid 1852:tid 1232] [client ::1:57588] AH02429: Response header name 'location ' contains invalid characters, aborting request, referer: http://localhost/project_exhibition/admin.php

Comment: The header should be `"Location:"` with no space before the colon. Not sure if that matters, but expressing it in the correct style can't hurt.

Comment: @tadman That was the thing. Just a extra space and everthing was going wrong.Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an error in your `header()` function, you are using:

```
header("location : admin.php");
```

This will throw the error you're getting because of the extra space between `location` and the colon. Change it to this (notice the space):

```
header("Location: admin.php");
```